# how can i get "byte[] scanRecord" in Altbeacon Library's didRangeBeaconsInRegion method

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I use didRangeBeaconsInRegion find beacon, and I want find each of beacon's `byte[] scanRecord`, how can I find it??thanks!!

```
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {

        @Override 
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Iterator<Beacon> iterator = beacons.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Beacon = iterator.next();
                }
            }

        }

   });
   try {
      beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
   } catch (RemoteException e) { }
}
```